# When resuming music player then music resumes but not the play and pause button states

Tags: android, drawable, audio-streaming, onresume

Below  is the  code  which   I use.By this code the background  music plays on all activities.But when  I come  back to this activity using  home  button  then music plays normally but the drawables will not resumed. That Mean if music is played and I went  back to that  activity  via  home  button then  play  button is shown  rather than the pause button but **I want that if music played on resume then button is pause and if not then show play button.**

Can you tell  what to do with  play  and pause  buttons on resuming  activties?

```
public class RadioActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements RadioListener{

private final String[] RADIO_URL = {"url "};
private ActionMenuView amvMenu;

ImageButton mButtonControlStart;
TextView mTextViewControl;
RadioManager mRadioManager = RadioManager.with(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    mButtonControlStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonControlStart);



    mRadioManager.registerListener(this);
    mRadioManager.setLogging(true);

    initializeUI();
    mButtonControlStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
    Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbarBottom.setTitle("Radio");
    amvMenu = (ActionMenuView) toolbarBottom.findViewById(R.id.amvMenu);
    amvMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        //  toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.activity_aboutus:
                    // TODO
                    Intent intent=new Intent(RadioActivity.this,Contact_us.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                // TODO: Other cases
                case R.id.menu_refresh:
                    // TODO
                    Intent intent1=new Intent(RadioActivity.this,Web.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_about:
                    Intent intent2=new Intent(RadioActivity.this,Song_rqst.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_item_share:
                    Intent intent3=new Intent(RadioActivity.this,Ratee.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;



            }
            return true;
        }
    });

  }

public void initializeUI() {
    mButtonControlStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonControlStart);
    mTextViewControl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewControl);

    mButtonControlStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mRadioManager.isPlaying()) {
                mRadioManager.startRadio(RADIO_URL[0]);
                mButtonControlStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.end);
            }
            else {
                mRadioManager.stopRadio();
                mButtonControlStart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRadioManager.connect();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mRadioManager.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onRadioLoading() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here.
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : LOADING...");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRadioConnected() {

}

@Override
public void onRadioStarted() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here.
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : PLAYING...");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRadioStopped() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : STOPPED.");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMetaDataReceived(String s, String s1) {
    //TODO Check metadata values. Singer name, song name or whatever you have.
}

@Override
public void onError() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you come back to your Music Play Activity `Oncreate()` is not called so your drawable resource load on `Onpause()` or `Onstart()`, Everytime `Oncreate()` is not calling.

Comment: The  problem is that I  play music  onclick so for that I should have to set some image like play at initial which is shown  when the activity is resumed also but dont  want this ?